# Change content of page in child theme using plugin

Tags: page-template, child-theme, conditional-content

I have a child theme in which I created a page template. I am able to show different content based on time of day by writing some PHP inside the actual page e.g.

```
if ( $time < '10:00'){
echo "The time is 10am and good morning.";
}
else
{
//show the page loop. 
}
```

I would like to show the message if it matches the condition if not then the usual page loop should be executed.

Will it be possible to do that using a plugin instead of creating page templates for each of my sites? It will be a lot easier just to install the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want to put the 'hello' thing. For instance, you could use the_content filter to put it before or after the content:

```
function wp_add_to_the_content($content) {
$content = 'Text before the content.' . $content . 'Text after the content';
return $content

add_filter('the_content', 'wp_add_to_the_content',10,1);
```

You'd need to add any CSS and other tags to format thing.

There are also filters for other parts of the post- like the post title, etc.

**Added**
The OP added to the question indicating he wants the message to be displayed before the loop is processed.

The answer to this question will provide guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741354/adding-content-before-the-loop ; use the `loop_start` filter which 'fires' before the loop is started.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'd like to skip the loop if the conditions are matched. The content is in the loop isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the_content is within the loop. It wasn't clear from your question exactly where you wanted to intercept/adjust things. There are many filters you can use to change things. You can use a filter that works before the loop, or one after. So, need more info on exactly **where** you want to display your message.